# Determine returntype of Lambda-Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following Code:

```
public class ScriptRuntime {
    public R Execute<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expression) {
        // ... do something ...
        return default(R);
    }
}
```

I call it like

```
var loc = AddIn.Context.ScriptRuntime.Execute<IAgentBaseScript, Vector3?>(x => x.GetInitialLocation(this));
```

I am asking me, if there would be a possibility to remove the defining of the returntype `R` and instead it should be get only from the expression?

For example when I call

```
var loc = AddIn.Context.ScriptRuntime.Execute<IAgentBaseScript>(x => x.GetInitialLocation(this));
```

and because the Interface `IAgentBaseScript` looks like

```
public interface IAgentBaseScript {
    Place GetInitialPlace(AgentBase agent);
    Vector3? GetInitialLocation(AgentBase agent);
}
```

it should theoretically be clear, that the returntype is `Vector3` because it is always the same as the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To infer the result type of `x => x.GetInitialLocation(this)`, the compiler would first have to infer the input type. As you noticed, it's not able to do it. The error message suggests to specify the type arguments of `Execute` method, but it's enough to let the compiler know what the type of `x` is:

```
scriptRuntime.Execute((IAgentBaseScript x) => x.GetInitialLocation(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without update Execute method, you can't because C# can't determine R.

Or else, you can update the method to

```
public Vector3? Execute<T>(Expression<Func<T, Vector3>> expression)
```

Or

```
public R Execute<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expression) where R : Vector3?
```